# iReport chart export in HTML format

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports, struts-1

I am using the iReport to make the JRXML file. To export this data using Java Struts, I am using the following code.

```
public ActionForward reportExport(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
  String reportType2=req.getParameter("reporttype");
  System.out.println("reportType2"+reportType2);
  String filename = "slademofinalreport1.jrxml";
  /*String reporttype = "pdf";*/
  String reporttype = reportType2;
  System.out.println(filename);
  System.out.println(reporttype);

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/epim","", "");
  String query="select projectname,processname,queuename,sladuedate,d.createddate,d.lastupdatedate,count(d.documentid)as numofdocuments,datediff(d.createddate,d.lastupdatedate)/count(d.documentid) as averagesla,datediff(d.sladuedate,d.createddate) as sladefined from epim.mstqueue mq,epim.userproject u,epim.documentqueuedetails d,epim.mstproject mproj,epim.mstprocess mproc where d.projectid=u.projectid and u.userid=13 and mproj.projectid=d.projectid and mproc.processid=d.processid and mq.queueid=d.queueid group by queuename ";

  PreparedStatement stmt1=con.prepareStatement(query);
  //stmt1.setInt(1,200);
  java.sql.ResultSet rs3=stmt1.executeQuery();
  /*Statement stmt1=(Statement) con.createStatement();
  java.sql.ResultSet rs3= stmt1.executeQuery("select projectname,processname,queuename,sladuedate,d.createddate,d.lastupdatedate,count(d.documentid)as numofdocuments,datediff(d.createddate,d.lastupdatedate)/count(d.documentid) as averagesla,datediff(d.sladuedate,d.createddate) as sladefined from epim.mstqueue mq,epim.userproject u,epim.documentqueuedetails d,epim.mstproject mproj,epim.mstprocess mproc where d.projectid=u.projectid and u.userid=13 and mproj.projectid=d.projectid and mproc.processid=d.processid and mq.queueid=d.queueid group by queuename");*/
  JRResultSetDataSource obj=new JRResultSetDataSource(rs3);

//  String path = application.getRealPath("/");
  JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:/subash/kmsnewwork/KMS_SUBASH/WebContent/jasperreport/"+ filename);
  System.out.println("Report Compiled...");
  JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,obj);
  System.out.println("Report Created...");
  ServletOutputStream ouputStream = res.getOutputStream();
  JRExporter exporter = null;

  if( "pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
  {
  res.setContentType("application/pdf");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.pdf\"");

  exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
  }
  else if( "rtf".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
  {
  res.setContentType("application/rtf");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.rtf\"");

  exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
  }
  else if( "html".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
  {
  exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
  exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,false);
  exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, new Boolean(false)); 

  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
  }
  else if( "xls".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
  {
  res.setContentType("application/xls");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.xls\"");

  exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
  }
  else if( "csv".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
  {
  res.setContentType("application/csv");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.csv\"");

  exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
  }

  try
  {
  exporter.exportReport();
  }
  catch (JRException e)
  {
  throw new ServletException(e);
  }
  finally
  {
  if (ouputStream != null)
  {
  try
  {
  ouputStream.close();
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
   System.out.println("exception thrown");
  }
  }
  }
  /*return mapping.findForward("goLoginPage");*/
  return mapping.findForward("goReportFilterPage");
 }
```

All the exporting format is getting the chart except the HTML. Can anyone help me? Should I do anything extra for HTML because the chart is not getting displayed using the HTML format?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other file formats, images are not imbedded in the html file, so special care is needed.

See [JRHtmlExporterParameter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporterParameter.html):

"An important issue is images. The HTML format stores images as separate files, so the exporter needs to know where these images will be stored. If they are stored on disk, the IMAGES_URI parameter will be initialized with a string containing the file name on disk. If they remain in memory, IMAGES_URI must point to a resource that is able to send the images to the browser (such as an image servlet, as shown in the webapp example). "